# Overwrite single file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, via Python code

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a `logs.txt` file at certain location, in a [Compute Engine VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#:%7E:text=An%20instance%20is%20a%20virtual,or%20the%20Compute%20Engine%20API.). I want to periodically backup (i.e. **overwrite**) `logs.txt` in a [Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets). Since `logs.txt` is the result of some preprocessing made inside a Python script, I want to also use that script to upload / copy that file, into the Google Cloud Storage bucket (therefore, **the use of [`cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) cannot be considered an option**). Both the Compute Engine VM instance, and the Cloud Storage bucket, stay at the same GCP project, so "they see each other". What I am attempting right now, based on [this sample code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object), looks like:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = "my-bucket"
destination_blob_name = "logs.txt"
source_file_name = "logs.txt"  # accessible from this script

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

generation_match_precondition = 0
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, if_generation_match=generation_match_precondition)

print(f"File {source_file_name} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}.")
```

If `gs://my-bucket/logs.txt` does not exist, the script works correctly, but if I try to **overwrite**, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2571, in upload_from_file
    created_json = self._do_upload(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2372, in _do_upload
    response = self._do_multipart_upload(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1907, in _do_multipart_upload
    response = upload.transmit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 153, in transmit
    return _request_helpers.wait_and_retry(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/_request_helpers.py", line 147, in wait_and_retry
    response = func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 149, in retriable_request
    self._process_response(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py", line 114, in _process_response
    _helpers.require_status_code(response, (http.client.OK,), self._get_status_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 105, in require_status_code
    raise common.InvalidResponse(
google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 412, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_folder/upload_to_gcs.py", line 76, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name, if_generation_match=generation_match_precondition)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2712, in upload_from_filename
    self.upload_from_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2588, in upload_from_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 4455, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.PreconditionFailed: 412 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/production-onementor-dt-data/o?uploadType=multipart&ifGenerationMatch=0: {
  "error": {
    "code": 412,
    "message": "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "conditionNotMet",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "If-Match"
      }
    ]
  }
}
: ('Request failed with status code', 412, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

I have checked the documentation for [`upload_from_filename`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_filename), but it seems there is no flag to "enable overwritting".

How to properly overwrite a file existing in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, using Python language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of [if_generation_match](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/generation_metageneration#using-ifgenerationmatch)

> As a special case, passing 0 as the value for if_generation_match
> makes the operation succeed only if there are no live versions of the
> blob.

This is what is meant by the return message "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold."

You should pass `None` or leave out that argument altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was that indeed! Maybe the docs should point to that information, rather than letting the reader "navigate through the whole thing". I'll accept your answer now.

Comment: There's a bug in the documentation generation, breaking the link to this part. Though it is a bit buried away, even if that link would work.

Comment: I have the same problem and I still don't get it. Leaving out the argument altogether or setting it to None still throws an error when I am trying to overwrite a file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: in my case, to force overwrite, I had to set both `if_generation_match` and `if_metageneration_match` to None, for some reason..